# Metric class in Analytics Reporting API v4 (Java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to make this example work https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#dimensions_and_metrics but I can't seem to find the right "Metric" Java library, the only Metric class I can find is "org.springframework.data.geo.Metric" and it is not the right one as it has nothing to do with the metrics in the Analytics Reporting API v4. Any help?

Comment: Not a java person but any way you can check that you have the right version of the client library v4 was just released is it possible you have the library for v3?  Its also possible that the Java client lib team hasn't generated the client library for v4 yet it was only released over the weekend.

Comment: Yep I think that's it, I can't find the client library v4. Thank you

Comment: Ping them on there issue forum see if its been built https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client/issues  They need to run a python generation script to pick up changes and New apis from the discovery services.  As far as I know its a manual thing they have to run.

Comment: There may also be an issue with the entry in discovery services preventing the client library's from building.  I have contacted google to get some feed back on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download and install the [Analytics Reporting API V4 Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/analyticsreporting/v4).

See the [Google APIs java client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) for details.

#### GRADLE:

Add the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-analyticsreporting:v4-rev1-1.21.0'
}
```

#### MAVEN

Add the following to your `pom.xml` file:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-analyticsreporting</artifactId>
      <version>v4-rev1-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```